# fastest way of doing a tar.gz from a tree of directories?

Tags: performance, tar

I've got a tree of directories with files like this:

```
.
|-- 00
|   |-- 00
|   |   |-- 00
|   |   |-- 01
|   |   |-- 02
|   |   |-- 03
|   |   |-- 04
|   |   |-- 05
[..]
|   |   |-- 97
|   |   |-- 98
|   |   `-- 99
|   |-- 01
|   |   |-- 00
|   |   |-- 01
[...]
```

There is about 200 files at the end of each directory, so a lot of files.
What would be the fastest way of making a tar.gz of the whole thing? Can I parallelize the task for many CPUs?

Comment: The bottleneck will be disk I/O, not CPU. Unless you have lots of small files on a RAID-1 device, you won't gain anything by parallelizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ext[234] filesystems, I find `dump` to be much faster than tar, especially with many small files, like a Maildir.  It also uses multiple cores for concurrent compression.  I suggest using -b 1024 for a 1mb block size, which works much better than the default 10kb block size.

Answer (score 9):

You only need to specify one (or more) the top level directory(s) to include, and `tar` will recursively dip into all it's children and wrap everything up:

```
tar cvfz output.tar.gz /path/to/top_folder
```

(As @forcefsck notes if the object is raw speed you can leave off the `v` option for less verbosity on the terminal. By not echoing every file it adds you save a little bit if I/O time talking to your terminal.)

Comment: change `cvfz` to `zcf`. verbose output slows the process and `f` must be at the end so it is immediately followed by the archive filename.

Comment: @forcefsck: You are right that the OP could leave off `v`, but unless the files are tiny it usually doesn't affect things that much and allows you to see that it did what you expected, which this OP needs to see. As for `f`, you are wrong, it does not need to be last. Try for yourself. Flags may come in any order as long as the *next argument* is the file name. In my head compression arguments like `z` and `j` makes a lot more sense that way.

Comment: about `f`, yes I am wrong :( somehow I remembered a case that it needed to be last. I guess my memory failed me. About `v`, the OP asked the _fastest_ way and we do need to consider the case of many small files.

Comment: @forcefsck: I edited my answer to not the speed consideration. *Arugment order* matters, the filename has to be the next argument, but arguments are separated by spaces. The wad of `cvfz` is a different syntax of flags. I think if you use the `-c -v -z -f filename` syntax you would have to do those in order. BSD's `tar` might only accept that syntax, I can't remember. However I have seen a lot of tutorials using my syntax but insisting `f` had to be last, which simply isn't the case.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the `--fast`, which is an alias to `-1`, option to gzip this way:

```
GZIP=--fast tar czf output.tar.gz /path/to/top_folder
```

or

```
GZIP=-1 tar czf output.tar.gz /path/to/top_folder
```

On some enviroments, the variable could be `GZIP_OPT` instead of `GZIP`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using pigz:

```
 tar --use-compress-program="pigz --best --recursive" -cf file.tar.gz folder/
 tar -cf file.tar.gz -I pigz folder/
```